# Spotify API: endpoint currently-playing podcast support

Tags: api, spotify

I'm developing a tool a tool (in Python 3) that gets my recently played track on Spotify. For that, I use the [official Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-users-currently-playing-track/) (you can try it there). When listening to music, I get a json containing the track, artist and much more info.

Unfortunately, this endpoint does not support listening to podcasts.  When I listen to a podcast, the returned json is

```
{
  "timestamp": 1545990763374,
  "context": {
    "external_urls": {
      "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/show/2tuQXnufTLetdGd7c24EfW"
    },
    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/shows/2tuQXnufTLetdGd7c24EfW",
    "type": "show",
    "uri": "spotify:show:2tuQXnufTLetdGd7c24EfW"
  },
  "progress_ms": 11357,
  "item": null,
  "currently_playing_type": "episode",
  "is_playing": true
}
```

which is not enough for my purposes. I googled a lot but did not find any endpoints of the Spotify API supporting podcasts.

Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: Spotify just announced a new Podcasts Web API today, which you can check out [here](https://developer.spotify.com/community/news/2020/03/20/introducing-podcasts-api/).

Comment: Wow - didn't expect an update after this long time.Thanks!
Unfortunately, the value behind "item" is still null when listening to podcasts, so I see no chance to get information such as podcast name (or even episode) and artist... Please correct me if I'm wrong! So the updated endpoints are not available, yet, because they are still in beta. Do you know when they might get generally available?

Comment: The value shouldn't be null anymore -- they're supposed to update the basic endpoints for listening as well (see the bottom of the linked blog post). https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing and https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player and now supposed to return info for podcasts as well.

Comment: Spotify generally takes a couple years to get to GA. However, from my experience with Spotify, I would say that it's quite unlikely that they'll mess with these endpoints after a year or so. The Web API is a core part of Spotify's dev community, and Podcasts are becoming a bigger part of Spotify's business model. These endpoints are here to stay, IMO.

Comment: I tried on https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-users-currently-playing-track/ and it's still null...

Comment: Try setting additional_types to episode -- then, you should get data no matter what.

Comment: Here's a link to that: https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-users-currently-playing-track/?additional_types=episode